# JavaScript/jQuery - scroll up button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I'm new to web development and came across a lot of tutorials on jQuery but there wasn't a lot on pure JS. I'm trying to convert this piece of code I found online which scrolls the page up when user clicks a button in the bottom right into pure JavaScript but I'm having some trouble.

```
function main() {
    $('.back-to-top').hide();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()>400){
            $('.back-to-top').fadeIn('fast');
        }else{
            $('.back-to-top').fadeOut('fast');
        }
    })

    $('.back-to-top').click(function(){
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 1000)

        return false;
    })
}
```

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work:

```
var scrollUp = document.getElementsByClassName('back-to-top');

window.onscroll = function(){
    if(window.pageYOffset >= 400){
        scrollUp.style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        scrollUp.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

scrollUp.onclick = function(){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

HTML

```
<a class="back-to-top" id="back-to-top" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h2 class="text">Scroll Up</h2>
</a>
```

This is for web development assignment, can I have some advice?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that document.getElementsByClassName('back-to-top') returns  an array-like object. Check documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Solution:

```
    var scrollUp = document.getElementsByClassName('back-to-top')[0];

    window.onscroll = function(){
      if(window.pageYOffset >= 400){
        scrollUp.style.display = 'block';
      }else{
        scrollUp.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    scrollUp.onclick = function(){
      window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
```

See working example here: 
   https://jsfiddle.net/9m7doq1m/

To avoid this issue, you can use the id selector (getElementById) instead of the class selector.

Comment: Is there a way of adding animation effect to make the transition smooth like in:     $('.back-to-top').click(function(){
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 1000)

Comment: I have a solution for the animation effect here: https://jsfiddle.net/9m7doq1m/2/. If you find my answer helpful, please accept the answer. An up vote would be greatly appreciated as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var scrollUp = document.getElementsByClassName('back-to-top');
scrollUp.onclick = function(){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

```css
#content {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" style="height:1000px">

</div>

<a class="back-to-top" id="back-to-top" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <h2 class="text">Scroll Up</h2>
</a>
```